# About viewbinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I would like to ask about ViewBinding.

The official

```
 buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

but it does not work.

Here is an example code.

Layout Code

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Kotlin Code

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener { }
```

Is there any solution to this problem?
I don't know why it is not working.

Android studio Vierson4.1.2
Gradle Viesion 6.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  as a parent in layout.xml

Example:- my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanner"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:squaredFinder="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

and in Kotlin.

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `layout` tag while using View Binding.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you enable view binding

```
 private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
 override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    
    binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener { }
    return binding.root
```

Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's `onDestroyView()` method.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        _binding = null
    }
```

For more details, [read](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var binding: (YourActivityBinding)

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState){
 binding = YourActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 setContentView(binding.root)
 binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener{ 
      })
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In Your Gradle (Modul):

```
android{
.
.
.
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
 }
}
```

After sync, in Your XML File, try to push (ALT+Enter) on your layout parent and choice

> Convert To Data Binding

[image]

Now in your Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
 }
}
```

Or in Your fragment:

```
class BlankFragment: Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentBlankBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(inflater)
    return binding.root
}
```

from now, for binding view, you should write something like this:

```
binding.textView.text = "test"
```

Comment: The question is about View Binding, not Data Binding.

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni This method covers both. Especially if you use MVVM structure.

Comment: But if you don't need to use Data Binding, then this won't work for View Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your wonderful answers.
I had forgot to create a binding class.
I was able to solve the problem successfully and the error has been resolved.

ADD Code

```
private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {

        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java: Add this in Gradle file

```
android {
...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Kotlin

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You inflated the view incorrectly, try this

```
val binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
    // Do something
}
```